# Панель управления на микросервисной архитектуре

Tags: архитектура, rest, веб-служба, сервисы

Ищу наиболее оптимальный вариант реализации проекта на микросервисной архитектуре.

Предполагается сделать много отдельных REST сервисов, каждый из которых решает свою небольшую задачу. К каждому из них пользователь должен получать доступ через единый доступ (логин и пароль / API ключ).

Далее все эти сервисы должны вызываться через единую панель управления через JS. Соответственно, все должно быть построено таким образом, чтобы пользователь, при желании, смог написать свою панель управления на основе всех этих сервисов.

Конкретно интересует:

- Как лучше всего реализовать единую аутентификацию для всех сервисов, если все они находятся на разных серверах?
- Как сделать механизм авторизации с разделением прав по разным микросервисам. Чтобы у пользователя был доступ к одному сервису, а к другому - нет, или не было бы доступа только к отдельным методам определенного сервиса.
- Как решается проблема выборки нужных данных по фильтру, когда сервис A связан с элементом сервиса B, который, в свою очередь, связан с сервисом C? Гипотетический пример: A - пользователи, B - платежные счета (каждый счет соотносится к пользователю), C - услуги (каждая услуга привязана к счету, с которого она автоматически оплачивается). Так как мы хотим уменьшить связность между сервисами, то сервис C не имеет связи с сервисом A. 
  Требуется выбрать все услуги у пользователя. Допустим, это решается выборкой всех счетов нужного пользователя, затем вторым запросом запрашиваются услуги по этим счетам. Но что, если у пользователя миллион счетов - все их придется предварительно загружать?
- Как сделать логирование, чтобы логи всех запросов сохранялись в едином месте, и чтобы пользователь их мог загрузить себе через тот же API? С тем же ключом доступа, к которому он получает доступ ко всем остальным сервисам. Как это реализовать, какую БД для этого выбрать? (если делать на Azure, есть ли там подходящие инструменты для этого?)

Answer (score 2):

У меня до сих пор нет практического опыта с микросервисами, но я бы выделил аутентификацию в отдельный сервис:

1. Метод А: получить в обмен на логин-пароль токен авторизации, действующий, скажем, час, либо получить 400 в связи с некорректной парой логин пароль (возможно, по канонам нужен немного другой код ответа).
2. Метод Б: проверить токен на валидность. Этим методом пользуются все микросервисы при каждом запросе, поэтому список валидных токенов с прицепленными к ним пользователями валяется в памяти. Здесь же, кроме самого токена, можно проверить авторизацию для тех или иных действий с сервисами.
3. Методы В и Г, необходимые при собственной авторизации в сервисах: выдать и проверить OTP (One-Time Password).

Это довольно простая схема; то, что вы описываете, похоже на OAuth, однако его стараются не применять без необходимости из-за сложности разработки. Впрочем, в ближайшем пакетном менеджере наверняка найдется пара библиотек, упрощающих жизнь донельзя.

> Как сделать логирование, чтобы логи всех запросов сохранялись в едином месте, и чтобы пользователь их мог загрузить себе через тот же API?

Я бы опять же обернул логи в отдельный микросервис. Внутри сервиса сидит логгер, который отправляет данные в конце запроса / по достижении определенного объема, при невозможности это сделать сбрасывает их на диск и пытается вызвать тревогу.